# Ошибка при повторном вызове команды discord net

Tags: c#, .net, discord

не могу пофиксить одну проблему которая довольно сильно мешает.
Объясняю вкратце - У меня есть дискорд бот на Discord.net 3.11.0 ([github](https://github.com/discord-net/Discord.Net)) который при вызове команды сначала скачивает песню а потом её воспроизводит все было бы хорошо, но если бы я не обнаружил ошибку которая до сих пор мешает сидеть с комфортом и слушать музыку это невозможность банально её выключить и после включить другой трек. При попытке вызвать остановку музыки происходит неведомое мне явление в c#, а именно когда я повторно включаю музыку после принудительного кика бота или команды /stop в боте вызывается исключение A task was canceled.
Вот вывод с консоли:

```
    [25.07.2023 22:38:00] (Info) [Gateway]: Ready
    Начинаю играть музыку по ссылке: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UmbXcO8****
    [25.07.2023 22:38:04] (Info) [Audio #1]: Connecting
    [25.07.2023 22:38:05] (Warning) [Audio #1]: Unknown OpCode (Hello)
    [25.07.2023 22:38:05] (Warning) [Audio #1]: Unknown OpCode (18)
    [25.07.2023 22:38:05] (Warning) [Audio #1]: Unknown OpCode (18)
    [25.07.2023 22:38:05] (Warning) [Audio #1]: Unknown OpCode (20)
    [25.07.2023 22:38:05] (Warning) [Audio #1]: Unknown OpCode (20)
    [25.07.2023 22:38:05] (Info) [Audio #1]: Connected
    audioClient Connected
    Треков в очереди: 1 Состояние: False
    ok
    22:38:15 Audio #1    System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
       at Discord.ConnectionManager.<>c__DisplayClass29_0.<<StartAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
    [25.07.2023 22:38:15] (Info) [Audio #1]: Disconnecting
    Очистил соединение
    AudioClient Destroyed
    [25.07.2023 22:38:15] (Info) [Audio #1]: Disconnected
    Начинаю играть музыку по ссылке: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UmbXcO8****
    [25.07.2023 22:38:26] (Info) [Audio #2]: Connecting
    [25.07.2023 22:38:26] (Warning) [Audio #2]: Unknown OpCode (Hello)
    [25.07.2023 22:38:26] (Warning) [Audio #2]: Unknown OpCode (18)
    [25.07.2023 22:38:26] (Warning) [Audio #2]: Unknown OpCode (18)
    [25.07.2023 22:38:26] (Warning) [Audio #2]: Unknown OpCode (20)
    [25.07.2023 22:38:26] (Warning) [Audio #2]: Unknown OpCode (20)
    [25.07.2023 22:38:26] (Info) [Audio #2]: Connected
    audioClient Connected
    Треков в очереди: 1 Состояние: False
    ok
 (тут я повторно вызвал музыку и почему то вызывается исключение)
    A task was canceled.
       at Discord.Audio.Streams.BufferedWriteStream.WriteAsync(Byte[] data, Int32 offset, Int32 count, CancellationToken cancelToken)
       at Discord.Audio.Streams.OpusEncodeStream.WriteAsync(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, CancellationToken cancelToken)
       at System.IO.Stream.<CopyToAsync>g__Core|29_0(Stream source, Stream destination, Int32 bufferSize, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       at System.IO.Strategies.BufferedFileStreamStrategy.CopyToAsyncCore(Stream destination, Int32 bufferSize, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       at DiscordElNegroBot.Utils.MusicQueue.<>c__DisplayClass22_0.<<PlayListPlayer>b__0>d.MoveNext() in C:\Users\allah\source\repos\DiscordElNegroBot\DiscordElNegroBot\Utils\MusicQueue.cs:line 80
    --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
       at DiscordElNegroBot.Utils.MusicQueue.<>c__DisplayClass22_0.<<PlayListPlayer>b__0>d.MoveNext() in C:\Users\allah\source\repos\DiscordElNegroBot\DiscordElNegroBot\Utils\MusicQueue.cs:line 81
    Треков в очереди: 0 Состояние: False
```

Сам код приложу на pastebin: https://pastebin.com/XsmphxT8
Прошу понять и простить если кривой код(Только недавно начал себя пробовать в c#)

Comment: `TaskCanceledException` - это нормальное поведение задачи, которое говорит о том, что данная задача была завершена, не стоит ее дальше использовать, создайте новую. Собственно, сделайте `try{ ... } catch (TaskCanceledException) {//завершилось}` и обрабатывайте эту ошибку так, как хотите. Хотите, ничего не делайте, хотите, создавайте по новой. Изучите, кто именно у вас вызывает эту ошибку, и этот объект создавайте по новой.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Но ведь рекурсия не может продолжаться если выходит исключение, оно мне попросту там не нужно это исключение

Comment: Это не отменяет того факта, что вы обращаетесь к задаче (`Task`), который уже завершен. Повторю, изучите свой код, посмотрите где именно выскакивает ошибка, посмотрите кто именно завершается, как, и когда, а затем либо пересоздавайте постоянно по новой этот объект, либо его завершение вынесите за пределы вашей "рекурсии". Например, попробуйте вынести `var discord = audioClient?.CreatePCMStream` за пределы, раз получили поток дискорда, дальше постоянно его используйте, а в конце делайте `.Dispose();`. А вообще, не пойму зачем тут рекурсия, достаточно списка треков и цикл.

Comment: Хорошо, попробую. Отпишу что получится

Comment: Полностью поменял логику проигрывания музыки и как не странно это помогло.